# how to create a angular notification factory

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use toastr for a success and error messages, I want to put it in a factory but i am getting a TypeError, with no details. 
Error Message

```
TypeError: object is not a function
at angular.js:8113
at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11573)
at angular.js:11659
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12702)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12514)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12806)
at done (angular.js:8379)
at completeRequest (angular.js:8593)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8532)angular.js:10072 (anonymous function)
```

Factory

```
'use strict';
myApp.factory('notificationFactory',
function () {
    var logIt;
    toastr.options = {
        "closeButton": true,
        "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
        "timeOut": "3000"
    };
    logIt = function (message, type) {
        return toastr[type](message);
    };
    return {
        success: function (message) {
            logIt(message, 'success');
        },
        error: function (message) {
            logIt(message, 'error');
        }
    };
  }
);
```

Controller

```
  $scope.EmailPdfNew = function () {
    var id = $scope.newCivil.CivilCaseId
    $http.get('/api/PdfCivil/' + id)
                .success(function () {
                    $http.post('/Home/EmailPdf')
                .success(notificationFactory)
                    .error(notificationFactory);
                });
}
```

update

```
 'use strict';
 myApp.factory('notificationFactory',
    function (toastr) {
    var logIt;
    toastr.options = {
        "closeButton": true,
        "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
        "timeOut": "3000"
    };
    logIt = function (message, type) {
        return toastr[type](message);
    };
    return {
        success: function (message) {
            logIt(message, 'success');
        },
        error: function (message) {
            logIt(message, 'error');
        }
    };
   }
);
```

injecting toastr into the function produces this error on page load

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: toastrProvider <- toastr <- notificationFactory
   errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=toastrProvider%20%3C-%20toastr   %20%3C-%20notificationFactory
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like you just need to inject it `function ('toastr') {`

Comment: Its seems to work - http://plnkr.co/edit/JJGCmwjHFLzVHNIPNUSy?p=preview

Comment: you where correct, I wasnt loading the toastr module

Comment: put it in a answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure to inject your module dependency and function.

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JJGCmwjHFLzVHNIPNUSy?p=preview)**

```
angular.module('plunker', ['toastr']);

...

app.factory('notificationFactory', function(toastr) {
```